# Simulate QKeyEvent on Whatever Widget InFocus

Tags: winapi, qt, events, keyevent

I want to Simulate a `QKeyEvent` on the Currently Focused Widget. That widget Might not belong to My Application even the widget may not be an Qt Widget at all. I just want to Simulate a QKeyEvent On Whatever Widget In Focus now.

I've tried `QApplication::postEvent(DG::Util::_desktopWidget, ev);`
Where `DG::Util::_desktopWidget` is the Primary Desktop Widget

```
QDesktopWidget* desktopWidget = new QDesktopWidget;
DG::Util::_desktopWidget = desktopWidget->screen(desktopWidget->primaryScreen());
```

But This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Qt you can only control widgets belonging to your app.
Therefore you can't send QKeyEvent to non-Qt apps, or Qt apps which are different processes.